# Ember dynamic MVC and templates

Tags: templates, model-view-controller, dynamic, ember.js

I am learning Ember.js 1.0.0-rc.3 and I would like to know the proper way to create a "dynamic MVC" app. What I mean by "Dynamic MVC" is that the only content I have when hitting the index page is a collection of entity names. The rest will be dynamically generated, i.e. model (data), eventually specific actions for the controllers, and specially templates.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
I have a collection of entities (such as ["User", "Customer", "Invoice", etc]).
I expect the route for each entity to be:

```
.../#/user/
.../#/customer/
.../#/invoice/
```

> `for each entity name`
>
> > this.resource("`entity name lower case`");

To make it simple for the explanation, hitting an entity route will display a view with 2 links. One to create a new entity, one to display a list of entities. The routes will then be:

```
.../#/user/                => will display a "Create" link and "List" link
.../#/user/create/         => sub route to display a form to create a User
.../#/user/list/           => sub route to display a collection of existing Users

.../#/customer/
.../#/customer/create/
.../#/customer/list/

...etc...
```

Now the templates for the sub routes ("*.../#/user/create/*", "*.../#/user/list/*", etc.) don't exist but instead will be loaded/created on demand. That's part of a new UI Design Pattern named SSD (Sketch, Schema, Data) where a template is generated based on a Sketch (a skeleton of a view), a Schema (specific to that view). Same for the actions.

**1) First question**. 
Knowing that I may end up with 100 entities+, **is it a correct approach to have a Controller, a Model, a View for each route**? And as well sub routes... I am a bit concerned about the performances here as all these objects are created when hitting the index page.

In the current sample, I will have the following Ember objects:

```
UserController, UserRoute, UserView
UserCreateController, UserCreateRoute, UserCreateView
UserListController, UserListRoute, UserListView
CustomerController, CustomerRoute, CustomerView
CustomerCreateController, CustomerCreateRoute, CustomerCreateView
CustomerListController, CustomerListRoute, CustomerListView
etc.
//it becomes easily heavy
```

I tried to link multiple paths to the same MVC objects but then it's hard to identify the current entity used. Analyzing the current path, if doable, seems really ugly.
For instance:

```
this.resource('entity', { path: '/' + user });
this.resource('entity', { path: '/' + customer });
this.resource('entity', { path: '/' + invoice });
//all attached to EntityController, EntityView and EntityRoute
//Could be working but hard to identity which entity User, Customer or Invoice is really used

this.resource('entity.create', { path: '/' + user + '/create' });
this.resource('entity.create', { path: '/' + customer + '/create' });
this.resource('entity.create', { path: '/' + invoice + '/create' });
//Same for EntityCreate
```

I also tried to use this.controllerFor('entity'), this.controllerFor('entity.create'), this.controllerFor('entity.list') but this doesn't reduce the number of objects and it makes the code more complicated than it should be.

**2) Second Question:**
To be able to work on dynamic templates, I implement setController() with an ajax call to load the necessary SSD which will be used to create the template and also the model.
I save the template to Ember.TEMPLATES[`template name`], change a data property, and attach an observer to the renderTemplate of the Route.

**Is it the proper way of dynamically changing a template?**

Here is a sample (not tested, just to see the process of loading/changing a template and model):

```
App["UserCreateRoute"] = Ember.Route.extend({
    templateName: "loading",  //display a temporary template while loading the template
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render(this.get('templateName'), {
            ///...
        });
    }.observes("templateChanged"),

    setupController: function(controller, model) {

        var self = this;

        $.when(` ajax load `).done(function( response ) {

            var templateName = xxx;  // based on the entity for instance "user/create"

            if (`template doesn't exist`) {
                Ember.TEMPLATES[templateName] = CreateMyTemplate( response );
                self.set("templateName", templateName);
            }

            //also change the model
            self.set("data", reponse.someData );

            //eventually add method to the controller?
            //...

            //tell renderTemplate to re-render
            self.set("templateChanged", new Date());

        })
    },

    model: function(params) {
        //simplified for sample
        return this.get("data")
    }
})
```

It's a bit long, thanks for reading!